# Maximise the sum of a number of variables given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph

I must've been banging my head over this question for hours; it's as follows (paraphrased to remove the silly story and context):

> Given an interval where there are N points, a point each on either
>   end, and a series of constraints on at most how far apart certain
>   pairs of points can be and at least how far apart certain pairs of
>   points must be, try to maximise the length of the interval. The points
>   can overlap.

It seems to boil down to this:

> There are N - 1 variables, each with length l(1..n-1) >= 0. There are a
>   list of constraints of this form:
>
> l(i) + l(i + 1) + .... l(j) <= C, or l(i) + l (i + 1) + ....l(j) >= C,
>
> and the task is to maximise l(1) + l(2) + .... l(n-1).

I hesitate to ask this on Maths Stackexchange since this is part of an exercise after an algorithms lesson in graph searching algorithms; do you see a way in which this can be transformed into a graph problem? How else would you solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to turn it to a graph problem: sort the numbers into ascending order. Take the smallest one, this is going to be the 'root', the (leftmost) starting point. Then take the next N elements which satisfy your constraints ie reachable from the starting point. These will be the children of the starting point and be represented as a directed edge. For each children repeat the above procedure until you run out of points. If at any iteration you are unable to add new children, that means your constraints make it impossible to reach the rightmost point of the interval...you are kind of doing a breadth first search.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this after some thoughts

1. multiply all "at least" constraints by -1 so they are in this form:

> -(l(i) + l(i + 1) + ... l(j)) <= -C

2. put all the "at most" constraints and the negative "at least" constraints together to make a matrix.
3. perform a form of "Gaussian elimination" on the matrix, paying attention to the way inequalities add
4. walk through the matrix and attempt to assemble a sum. This step should be easy.

The cases having no valid solution and infinitely many solutions should be detectable in a way similar to normal matrices used to solve a system of linear equations.

What are your thoughts?